# Skobbler Compass icon tap area is wrong

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm using Skobbler Maps API 2.5.1

If I tap on the bottom-left area of the compass icon, it does not trigger "onCompassSelected".  It appears the tap area is misplaced to the top-right, so for example I can tap right above the compass icon and it will trigger onCompassSelected.

Is there anyway to adjust the tap area for the compass icon?

Comment: Sorry I could not understand what you are asking

Comment: I'm referring to the Skobbler Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround we ended up using was to add logic in "onSingleTap" to determine if the screen point for the tap corresponds to where the compass is on the screen.